# Automatically managing dependencies in an OSGi plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi

I noticed in the ordinary, standalone, maven projects that the libraries (their jars) are automatically copied to the projects folder. You only have to add the correct entries to the pom.xml file and a few moments later, the jars appear in the project. I guess this is great, since the suitable library jars (for linux, windows, arm, ...) are downloaded. When I try to add the entries to the pom.xml file in my OSGi plugin (using the Equinox framework), those files are not automatically downloaded. I was wondering if such automatical dependency management is also possible in OSGi plugins and if it is, how can it be set?

Comment: What do you mean by OSGi plugin? There are several plugins for Eclipse and maven to support OSGi development. Which ones do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly, since I'm a beginner at this. This is the tutorial I'm following: https://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/one/Developer

Comment: If you're new to OSGi you might want to take a look at OSGi enRoute to get a better understanding. Since it uses Bndtools it is a lot easier to get started with the intricacies of OSGi then plain maven. It is currently supporting maven repositories for dependencies though it uses Gradle for CI builds.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The problem is, I've already build some plugins, but I manually copied the necessary dependencies (on my windows pc). I'd like to know, if the scenario, which I mentioned in the original post is possible, so I could deploy them to a linux (for example a Raspberry Pi) machine.

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: For your own information, and for others trying to help you, it looks like you are using Eclipse PDE with Maven Tycho. It's unfortunate that OM2M has chosen these tools for their tutorial since it makes things much harder than necessary.